# Remove tabs and blank lines with grep/sed/tr

Tags: bash, unix, sed, grep, tr

I have a text file looking like this:

```
> cat test.txt

    “Il faut attendre l’expiration du cache.”


    “C'est sûrement un problème lié à l'hébergement.”


    “Tu as du cliquer de travers.”


> cat -e test.txt
$
    �M-^@M-^\Il faut attendre l�M-^@M-^Yexpiration du cache.�M-^@M-^]$
    $
$
    �M-^@M-^\C'est sûrement un problème lié à l'hébergement.�M-^@M-^]$
    $
$
    �M-^@M-^\Tu as du cliquer de travers.�M-^@M-^]$
    $
```

I want my file to look like that:

```
> cat test.txt
“Il faut attendre l’expiration du cache.”
“C'est sûrement un problème lié à l'hébergement.”
“Tu as du cliquer de travers.”
```

In order to do that, I tried `sed -e 's/^\s*//' -e '/^$/d' test.txt`
but I can't get the result I want. It only remove one blank line and I still haven't figured out how to remove the tabs.

```
> sed -e 's/^\s*//' -e '/^$/d' test.txt
    “Il faut attendre l’expiration du cache.”

    “C'est sûrement un problème lié à l'hébergement.”

    “Tu as du cliquer de travers.”
```

How can I remove all empty lines and the tabs at the beginning of the strings ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't have GNU Sed. With GNU Sed your sed command should work.

There is another solution that you could try out:

```
sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e '/^$/d' test.txt
```

or, to just remove use spaces and tabs:

```
sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' -e '/^$/d' test.txt
```